# How to install go-server?

Tags: 14.04, permissions

I want to install Go-Servre on my Ubuntu 14.04and I'm following this doc 
http://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/installation/install/server/linux.html#debian-based-distributions-ie-ubuntu

According to the doc this is the procedure:

```
$ echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/gocd/gocd-deb/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list
$ wget --quiet -O - "https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=gocd" | sudo apt-key add -
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install go-server
```

However, I have problem in first line when I run the command and I get following reply:

```
$ echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/gocd/gocd-deb/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list: Permission denied
```

I even tried to change the permission but still I'm getting error:

```
$ sudo chmod +x  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list
[sudo] password for hesam: 
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list’: No such file or directory
```

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I found the solution based on your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the first (`echo ...`) command as a privileged user. So first switch to root by `sudo su`, then run the `echo` command.

Doing `sudo echo ...` will not work, as the `>` redirection will be done before `sudo` is executed.

Comment: Thanks for "...the > redirection will be done before sudo is executed." didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Permission is denied because you are trying to create a file in a privileged location. And `sudo echo` doesn't work. However, there is a way to work around this problem.

You can use either of the following commands to accomplish the first step:

```
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/gocd/gocd-deb/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list
```

or

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/gocd/gocd-deb/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gocd.list'
```